# Tell Django to ignore user_passes_test decorator when running tests?

Tags: django, django-testing

Is there a way to tell the default Django test runner to ignore the user_passes_test decorator when running a test?  I have the following test:

```
# test.py
from django.test import TestCase
class TestFeedbackQuestionResponseFormIT(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_feedback_no_error(self):
        self.client.login(username='admin', password='adminpassword')
        form_inputs = {'response_text': '', 'close_issue': False}
        response = self.client.post(reverse('review-feedback-or-question', kwargs={'fqid': 1}), form_inputs)
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('review-feedback-or-question-queue'), status_code=302, target_status_code=200)
```

When I run this test I get the following error:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_feedback_no_error (footer.tests.test_forms.TestFeedbackQuestionResponseFormIT)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/www/proj/footer/tests/test_forms.py", line 13, in test_feedback_no_error
    self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('review-feedback-or-question-queue'), status_code=302, target_status_code=200)
  File "/Users/me/venv/my_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 306, in assertRedirects
    (url, expected_url))
AssertionError: Response redirected to 'http://testserver/sign_in/?next=/admin/review/feedback_or_question/1/', expected 'http://testserver/admin/review/feedback_or_question/'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The reason this is occurring is because I'm using the aforementioned decorator in my urls.py file:

```
# conf/urls.py
url(r'^admin/review/feedback_or_question/(?P<fqid>\d+)/$',
        user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff)(review_feedback_or_question),
        {'template': 'review_feedback_or_question.html'},
        name='review-feedback-or-question'),
```

I've tried to log the admin in when the test starts but Django's test runner doesn't seem to recognize it.  Is there any way to tell the Django test runner to ignore the decorator when I run the test?

Thanks.

Comment: No, that's pretty much impossible. You have to log in a staff user.

Comment: You want your test to accurately represent the environment (i.e. user that is staff) it should be testing. If you test against a user that is not staff and it succeeds, and for whatever reason code unintentionally changes that logic, there is no test to alert you.